# How to fix "Folder is Empty" in one partition of external hard drive in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have a 3TB hard drive, which has two partitions. The first partition has 1TB storage and the 2nd has 2TB storage.

My second partition(2TB) has 1.1TB data, but when I mount it on ubuntu it displays `Folder is Empty`.

I can see the content of the first partition(1TB) and works well.

I also opened the hard drive in Parrot OS and it opened regularly and had no issue.

I think that this issue is due to unexpectedly unplugging the hard drive from the computer.

**update**
i checked filesystem using this command `sudo lsblk -f`:

```
sdb                                                                                
├─sdb1
│     ntfs                            
└─sdb2  // this is the partition that has issue
      ntfs
```

when I run `sudo fsck /dev/sbd2`:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
```

Comment: If you think there might be a problem with the partition try using fsck. https://linuxhandbook.com/fsck-command/ Just remember the partition you want to check has to be unmounted

Comment: Thanks, @PonJar I read the article and did as per instructions. when I run `sudo fsck -p  /dev/sdb2`  the result is : `fsck from util-linux 2.36.1` and nothing else.

Comment: What were you expecting the -p option to do? There is a -P option that you shouldn’t really use. What was your exit code? I don’t think you allowed it to finish. What filesystem are you using on this partition?

Comment: as the article: `generally, you can use -p to allow fsck to automatically apply repairs.` I have updated the question and answered these questions.

Comment: Try to manually mounting the partition to a new mount point and see if that works .... i.e. `mkdir ~/new` then `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 ~/new`

Comment: Thanks @Raffa, I did as your said, but still the same issue.

Comment: Ok apologies, there seems to be some misleading information in that article. There is no -p option according to the Linux manual page. There is a -P option (capital P) which doesn’t do what the article says. However fsck will be of no use to you because your problem is with an NTFS formatted partition. fsck is for Linux filesystems. I’m guessing sdb2 has been locked by Windows. Are you dual booting.

Comment: No, I just use Ubuntu  and I have partitioned the hard disk in windows.

Comment: You need to use Windows tools to fix any issues with NTFS partitions. That is one of the reasons it’s a bad idea to use NTFS on a system with no Windows installation. You haven’t said if this is a dual boot system. If it is then use CHKDSK to check the partition. If not you need to connect it to a Windows system to do that. Either way I would focus on creating a back of all the data and then repartition. If this is standalone Linux then use a Linux filesystem like ext4. If it’s dual boot then use ExFAT. If either of these two partitions contain a Windows system I wouldn’t mount it in Linux

Comment: It is not dual boot. I only use ubuntu. Thank you very much.